# Ccos2d can not found CCMoveTo

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I´m starting using cocos2D. In the init function of the helloworld class, I,m trying to create a CCMoveTo object but I can not, it does not find it.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you post your init code?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are either using the latest version of cocos2d and created your project via SpriteBuilder or you are using an older version of cocos2d and created your project via an Xcode template. If so...

If you are using the latest version of cocos2d, but are using learning materials that are older, then things have changed a little. For move actions try using:

```
CCActionMoveTo
CCActionMoveBy
```